Evaluated characters of a finite abelian group sum to zero
i would like to show :
If $G$ is a finite abelian group and $G^*$ the set of character of the group $G$ then for any $a\in G$ :
$$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\chi\in G^*}\chi(a) = \begin{cases}
        1 & \text{if } a = e_G    \\
        0 & \text{if } a \neq e_G
    \end{cases}
$$
The case $a=e_G$ is easy but i have some trouble with the other one. For now, i have done :
As $G$ is a finite group then every element has finite order. Let $n$ be the order of $a$, i.e. $a^n = e_G$. Therefore :
$$
    1=\chi(e_G)=\chi(a^n)=\chi(a)^n
$$
Thus, $\chi(a)$ is a $n-$th root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$. Since $n$ divides $|G|$, by Lagrange theorem, then $\chi(a)$ is also a $|G|-$th root of unity.
I would like to show that for any $\chi,\chi'\in G^*$ then $\chi(a)$ and $\chi'(a)$ are distincts $|G|-$th root of unity. Then as $|G|=|G^*|$ (because $G\cong G^*$),
$$\sum_{\chi\in G^*}\chi(a)$$
is the sum of $|G|$ distincts $|G|-$th root of unity which is well known to be zero. \
Thanks in advance

This is the regular character.

Try multiplying the sum of characters with a fixed character $\tau(a)$ evaluated in $a$ and see what you can say about the new sum especially if $\tau(a)\neq 1$.

If $a \neq 1$, there is some $\sigma \in G^*$ with $\sigma(a) \neq 1$. Then $$\sigma(a) \cdot \sum_{\chi \in G^*} \chi(a) = \sum_{\chi \in G^*} (\sigma \chi)(a) = \sum_{\chi \in G^*} \chi(a)$$ implies that the sum is zero.

Try to think about it.
